# HTTP Request 500 when I call mysqli_connect with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysqli

I want to use a database to store user data. I am running an Apache server with PHP and MySQL installed. When I try mysqli_connect, there is a HTTP 500 error. This is my code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","database");
mysqli_close($con);
```

I also checked the Apache log; here's what it said:

> [Time] [error] [client localhost] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in [Document Address] on line 78, referer: [URL]

and

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext/php_mysqli.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

Also, `var_dump(function_exists('mysqli_connect'));` outputs `bool(false)`.

I've uncommented `extension=php_mysqli.dll` in php.ini, checked the ext directory and there is a php_mysqli.dll file in it, checked other StackOverflow (and other) questions like this, but none of this answered it for me.

Comment: You may need to add `extension=mysqli.dll` to your php.ini file.

Comment: I have. Let me edit the question.

Comment: Did you restart the server after enabling the extension?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes, I did.

Comment: check file is **exists**?  **php/ext/mysqli.dll**
if not **exists**, please download it :)

Comment: Go with `phpinfo()` or `phpinfo(INFO_MODULES)` and check if `mysqli` is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

test phpinfo () and make sure that the function is activated